# Card with horizontal ScrollView

Tags: android, mobile-application, material-design, guidelines, card-views

[image: Screenshot from current UI]

I'd like to ask how I should design this vertical RecyclerView while the ChildViews are cards now I'd like to make a Card with the RecyclerView in it but since Cards inside a Card equals Cardception I'm asking myself how this item could be designed. Is Tiles a suitable approach?

Comment: Programming questions are better suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: Excuse me you mabye have not quiet understood my question, the question was how to _actually design_ an item that is part of a vertical RecyclerView inside of a CardView without misstreating the guidelines and I was wondering if vertical scrolling Tiles inside the CardView would be a suitable approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mockup seems just fine and doesn't break the Material guidelines.

In the Google Play Store app, Google also combines vertical and horizontal scrolling, so don't worry about that.

Visually, I would not recommend having cards within cards, but you don't do that in your mockup. If you wanted to have multiple elements in a row inside a card, then I'd recommend simply separating them by space, without a card behind them.

Answer (score -1):

Set the recycler view layout manager to horizontal:

```
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new 
LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, 
false));
```

Comment: this is true,IDK why you got Downvotes.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: your answer is right, still, you got downvote strang.